# Drupal 7 taxonomy root terms view display

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-views, taxonomy, drupal-taxonomy

I currently have a taxonomy setup like so using Drupal 7:

```
-root1
--child1
--child2
-root2
--child3
--child4
```

Something like a country state/province hierarchy.

What I would like to do is create a view for the different terms based on the parent id. So if a user clicks on root1 you would see child1 and child2. Now I've currently have this setup using a page view and using a Configure contextual filter: `Taxonomy term: Parent term`.

Here's my problem, how do I display the root terms? Basically I want to pass nothing in and maybe somehow setup a default value so that root1 and root2 are displayed on the page.

Current settings:

> WHEN THE FILTER VALUE IS IN THE URL OR A DEFAULT IS PROVIDED
>   Specify validation criteria
>   Validation: Taxonomy Term
>   Filter value type: Term name converted to Term ID

I've also tried setting it up as a Term ID only and setting a default value of 0 hoping this would grab any terms with the parent ID of 0 but nothing displays.

Comment: So in order to display just the root terms you can a parent relationship. Also add a FILTER CRITERIA and set it to your taxonomy vocabulary and then add another filter that checks if parent is empty: (Parent) Taxonomy term: Vocabulary (empty).  But this again will only show root level or top level terms and you won't be able to view children now.

Answer (score 1):

This problem in D6 could be resolved easily using [Hierchical Select](http://drupal.org/project/hierarchical_select). But the HS module is not fully ported yet.
The issue page about the hs_views submodule:
http://drupal.org/node/1170192